# How can I properly run Detectron2 on Videos?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I'm currently working with Detectron2 for people detectios in videos, I've been trying to run the following code to read a video file, make the prediction frame by frame and record a video with the processed frames, but I am getting an empty video file. The environment that I've created for this is located in Colaboratory and has the following versions (python 3.6 , opencv 4.2.30).
I'm new on this but I would truly appreciate if someone could give me an idea

This is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import detectron2
from detectron2.utils.logger import setup_logger
setup_logger()
# import some common libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2
# import some common detectron2 utilities
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import Visualizer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('piloto legger 1.mp4')
hasFrame, frame = cap.read()
FPS = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_width = frame.shape[1]
frame_height = frame.shape[0]
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('out.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'), FPS, (frame_width, frame_height))
while cv2.waitKey(1) < 0:
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()
    if not hasFrame:
        cv2.waitKey()
        break
    cfg = get_cfg()
    cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-Keypoints/keypoint_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
    cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7  # set threshold for this model
    cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-Keypoints/keypoint_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
    predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)
    outputs = predictor(frame)
    v = Visualizer(frame[:,:,::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale=1.2)
    v = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
    imagen = (v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
    cv2.imwrite('POSE detectron2.png', imagen)
    video_writer.write(imagen)

cap.release()
video_writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you very particular about this code? or You just need to process the video using detectron2. There are code that comes with detectron2 to get the video you ask for.

Comment: I've seen it, I tried to run a demo on the video but I got an empty file. The code that I'm using now is a version of one I saw in a function that is on the repositoy of Detectron2

Comment: Can you try visualising the frames when they are processed and ensure you are writing the redirected data to the video?

Comment: Already did it. Before writing the processed frames I print them ( with this line cv2.imwrite('POSE detectron2.png', imagen) and the data is good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used your code as a starting point, and took some ideas from the Detectron2 examples in order to make it work.

The problem seems to have been something with the fourcc-argument of the `VideoWriter`, but may also have been related to your code using `Visualizer` instead of `VideoVisualizer` (and with a scale of 1.2, which made the image the wrong size for the `VideoWriter`).

The code below works for me (and is also a lot faster, as the predictor and visualizer are defined outside of the loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -- coding: utf-8 --

import detectron2
from detectron2.utils.logger import setup_logger
setup_logger()
# import some common libraries
import numpy as np
import tqdm
import cv2
# import some common detectron2 utilities
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.utils.video_visualizer import VideoVisualizer
from detectron2.utils.visualizer import ColorMode, Visualizer
from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog
import time

# Extract video properties
video = cv2.VideoCapture('video-input.mp4')
width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
frames_per_second = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
num_frames = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

# Initialize video writer
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('out.mp4', fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), fps=float(frames_per_second), frameSize=(width, height), isColor=True)

# Initialize predictor
cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml"))
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7  # set threshold for this model
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = model_zoo.get_checkpoint_url("COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml")
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

# Initialize visualizer
v = VideoVisualizer(MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), ColorMode.IMAGE)

def runOnVideo(video, maxFrames):
    """ Runs the predictor on every frame in the video (unless maxFrames is given),
    and returns the frame with the predictions drawn.
    """

    readFrames = 0
    while True:
        hasFrame, frame = video.read()
        if not hasFrame:
            break

        # Get prediction results for this frame
        outputs = predictor(frame)

        # Make sure the frame is colored
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Draw a visualization of the predictions using the video visualizer
        visualization = v.draw_instance_predictions(frame, outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))

        # Convert Matplotlib RGB format to OpenCV BGR format
        visualization = cv2.cvtColor(visualization.get_image(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        yield visualization

        readFrames += 1
        if readFrames > maxFrames:
            break

# Create a cut-off for debugging
num_frames = 120

# Enumerate the frames of the video
for visualization in tqdm.tqdm(runOnVideo(video, num_frames), total=num_frames):

    # Write test image
    cv2.imwrite('POSE detectron2.png', visualization)

    # Write to video file
    video_writer.write(visualization)

# Release resources
video.release()
video_writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thank a lot for this , it worked for my use case as well, though one problem was it was saving ALL the frames in a video , is there a way to only save every nth frame or something similar ?